# Markdown lists don't follow order

Tags: github, markdown, wiki

I'm trying to create a wiki and I have this issue
Let's say I have something like this:

> 1. Item 1
> 2. Item 2
>
> `I need do add this code on this step`
>
> 3. Item 3

But it displays something like this:

> 1. Item 1
> 2. Item 2
>
> `I need do add this code on this step`
>
> 1. Item 3

I need it to keep following the order. How can I fix this?

Comment: Once you stop the list items it's a new list. You need to do it manually.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use the code below:

````
1. Item 1

2. Item 2

    ```
    code
    ```

3. Item 3
````

It produces this:

1. Item
2. Item 2

   `code`
3. Item 3

Comment: Muchas gracias!

Answer (score 0):

Indent the code block with 8 spaces, or indent it with 4 spaces but surround it by triple backticks:

```
1. Item 1
2. Item 2

        some
        code

3. Item 3
```

or

````
1. Item 1
2. Item 2

    ```
    some
    code
    ```

3. Item 3
````